# Magento 2: Setup 505 issue in mamp 5.5

Tags: magento2.3

When I have tried to setup magento 2 in mamp 5.5 I got an error.

This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: which os used ??

Comment: am using mac os mojave

Answer (score 1):

**Give 777 permission to project root directory.**

> If still issue is there please add below code to the top of
>   `index.php` file. It will display all php errors on page refresh and
>   solve that specific issue.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: still same issue i have tried your solutions

Comment: Use second option. And check which error is displaying on front end.

Comment: i have tried second option also same issue

Comment: put info.php file in root directory and check configuration is ok or not.